The Riemannian distance metric $g=f(t)dt^2$ is induced by the the straight line path
Suppose $f(t)$ is a smooth positive function on $\mathbb{R}$ so that $g=f(t)dt^2$ is a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to show that $g$ induces a complete metric space if and only if both of the improper integrals
$$\int_0^\infty \sqrt{f(t)}dt,  \int_{-\infty}^0 \sqrt{f(t)}dt$$ diverge.
In doing so, I need the result that $d_g(x,y) = |\int_x^y \sqrt{f(t)}dt|$. If we take $\gamma:[x,y]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $\gamma(t)=t$ for $x<y$ then we have $L_g(\gamma) = \int_x^y |\gamma'(t)|_g dt = \int_x^y \sqrt{f(t)}dt$.
However, the distance is defined to be the infimum of all such $L_g(\gamma)$ for all piecewise smooth curve segment $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $\gamma(a)=x,\gamma(b)=y$.
How can I show that the straight line path gives the infimum for this metric? I would greatly appreciate some help.

Any other path is longer. Break the integral into pieces where the path is monotone one way or the other.

@TedShifrin If $\gamma$ is monotone on $[a,b]$ let's say $\gamma(a)=x, \gamma(b)=y$ and $\gamma'\ge 0$ here then we have $L_g(\gamma) = \int_a^b \gamma'(t) \sqrt{f(t)}dt$, but how is this longer than $\int_x^y \sqrt{f(t)}dt$?

It’s not. They are equal. But you have a typo in your integral.

@TedShifrin Okay so I think you mean if $\gamma$ is strictly monotone, the left integral is just a reparametrization of the right one. So any other path will be longer if they are not strictly increasing or decreasing because they will trace back. But I could you locate where a typo is in my integral?

Look at $L_g(\gamma)$.

@TedShifrin I'm sorry I really don't see what's wrong. In general, we should have $L_g(\gamma)=\int_a^b |\gamma'(t)|\sqrt{f(t)}dt$ but I assumed $\gamma'\ge 0$ here, what am I missing?

You need $\sqrt{f(\gamma(t))}$, no?
